# Multi select Tree View always shows group names instead of child names

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, treeview, treeviewitem

I am using multi select tree view library for making my pull down list. As of now when we are selecting the child names , the above text field is populating with child node name. Only when all the child nodes are selected the Parent Node name will be shown in the text box. I want to always show the parent node name if any child node of that parent node is selected instead of requiring all the child nodes to be selected.

https://www.cssscript.com/multi-select-tree/

I tried all the inbuilt options I understood . But it is always showing the child node name in the text box.